# Disabling UIBarButtonItems in Nav Bar and Stopping Secondary Popvers

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, popover

The issue is as follows: I have an iOS 9 app (Swift) with a nav bar that houses a bunch of UIBarButtonItems with segues to several UINavigationControllers that finally display tables, views etc. as popovers. Of course tapping one of these buttons does not automatically disable the other UIBarButtonItems in the nav bar and the user is free to tap them. With a popover already displaying however we get the following warning as this is against the HIG and also grounds for rejection:

```
Attempt to present UINavigationControllerViewController which is already presenting (null)
```

To take care of the issue once a popover is displaying a) the remaining UIBarButtonItems need to be disabled and b) displaying additional popovers needs to be halted.

[image: button A is still enabled]

So what is the best cause of action here? The isBeingPresented flag of the popover's view controller is not available in the governing view controller because one can't create outlets of one view controller in another and the navigationController's viewControllers array doesn't include external navigation controllers or their descendants.

My lame workaround involves a global appIsPresentingPopover Bool which is set to true in viewDidLoad and to false in viewDidDisappear in the mentioned view controllers. That Bool is then tested in the governing view controller's prepareForSegue method to stop additional popovers from displaying. It is also kvo'ed to disable any enabled UIBarButtonItems which now all have an outlet. Ugly!

What is the standard way of handling this common scenario?

Comment: Can you detect when a new popover is presented, and close the other one?  IMO it's best to handle it this way if you can, rather than disable a button. Users would expect to be able to toggle between popovers without having an annoying tap in between.

Comment: Thanks, I completely agree as for the UX and one would of course avoid updating the enabled status of any UIBarButtonItems altogether. The main issue however remains as it is crucial to first close existing popovers before doing anything else to avoid the mentioned warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly simple solution and much more elegant than my initial attempt. I added segue identifiers for all involved popups and a UIViewController class variable. In prepareForSegue I set the variable to the destination view controller. Then in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier I simply check whether that popover variable is nil. If it is not, I dismiss the UIViewController and set it to nil. Finally I also followed Beau Nouvelle's suggestion and kept those buttons lit so users can switch directly between popovers. Thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant. May as well give your own answer a nice big tick!

Comment: Heh, yeah - works like a charm and is easily extensible.